# Which command lists all `venv` environments?

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv, virtual-environment

Similar to using `lsvirtualenv` for displaying all environments created by `virtualenv` (Python 2), what is the command for listing all environments created by  `venv` (Python 3)?

Comment: If you want to go all out with it you could [extend the venv API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#api) to log or store created environments in the `post_setup` step

Comment: @sinoroc note that will also include anything with site-packages e.g. environments created through a tool like virtualenv too

Comment: @BradSolomon I think these _false positive_ concerns (or at least similar ones) are already mentioned in that other post. Your idea with extending `venv`'s code is interesting.